# Как создать 1 \ несколько потоков Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qtcreator, qthread

Сидел очень долго, обрыл много информации и так как я новичек мне часто не понятно то или иное.
Потоки мне нужны для того чтобы программа не крашилась(юзер выбирает файл и программа его читает)

Как мне создать поток?(Знаю только как создать поток в C++, а с Qt не разобрался)

**Есть код в mainwindow.cpp:**

```
void func_() {
    qDebug() << "Flow started!";
}


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    thread = new QThread();
    dil = new Dialog(this);

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QString file_name = QFileDialog :: getOpenFileName (NULL, "123123", ".", "*.txt");
    QString file_name_name = QFileInfo(file_name).fileName();
    if (file_name != "") {
        ui->label->setText(file_name_name);
    }

    thread(func_).start() // Не понимаю как нужно написать ;(((
    
}
```

**Также есть код в mainwindow.h:**

```
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_action_2_triggered();

    void on_action_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Dialog *dil;
    QThread *thread;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен :(

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/150274/

Answer (score 1):

```
SomeClass* worker = new SomeClass(r_type);
QThread* thread = new QThread;
worker->moveToThread(thread);

connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(myslot()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
thread->start();
```

Comment: Можете подсказать что и куда писать пожалуйста?

Comment: Вам нужно объявить еще один класс, и добавить метод func_ в слоты этого класса. Далее по примеру сверху

Comment: Можете пожалуйста дописать код? Я понимаю мало в этом
Пытался уже создать класс в cpp файле, там ошибки лезут, я так понимаю в .h нужно тоже его создавать или объявлять, но не понимаю эту часть работы я

Comment: сделал более подробный пример. Смотрите на новый ответ к данному вопросу

Answer (score 0):

По вашей просьбе сделал более подробный пример

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>

#include <someclass.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QThread *thread = new QThread;
    SomeClass *someClass = new SomeClass;

    someClass->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(thread, &QThread::started, someClass, &SomeClass::func);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater);

    thread->start();
}
```

someclass.h

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#define SOMECLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class SomeClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SomeClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void func();

};

#endif // SOMECLASS_H
```

someclass.cpp

```
#include "someclass.h"
#include <QDebug>

SomeClass::SomeClass(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{

}

void SomeClass::func()
{
    qDebug() << "started";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, сейчас попробую это.